# How can I get Vue.js to be reactive for changes to dynamically added array properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, object-properties, vue-reactivity

In Vue.js, I have a data object with dynamically added/edited properties that are themselves arrays. For example, the property starts out as follows:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        vals: {}
    };
}
```

And over time, through various button clicks, etc., `vals` may look like the following (with the actual property names and values being 100% dynamic based on a number of factors):

```
vals: {
    set1: [
        {
            prop1: 123,
            prop2: 'hello'
        },
        {
            prop1: 456,
            prop2: 'bye'
        }
    ],
    set2: [
        {
            prop3: 'Why?!',
            prop4: false
        }
    ]
}
```

As the array properties (i.e., `set1` and `set2`) are changed, I want to be able to react to those changes.

For example, I may do something like the following in my code:

```
var prop = 'set1';

this.vals[prop].push({
    {
        prop1: 789,
        prop2: 'hmmm...'
    }
});
```

However, when I do that, the component is not updating (I presume because I am pushing an object onto the end of a subarray of an object; and Vue.js doesn't seem to track those changes).

I have been able to force the component to be reactive by doing `this.$forceUpdate();` after the above `push`, but I imagine there has to be a more eloquent way of getting Vue.js to be reactive when it comes to objects being pushed onto the end of object subarrays.

Does anyone know of a better way to try to do what I am trying to achieve? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you're adding a new property to an object or changing a value within an array, you need to use [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

```js
Vue.set(this.vals, prop, [ /* ... */ ])
```

Ideally, you should define all your properties up front so Vue doesn't have to invalidate computed properties depending on your data model's shape. Even if you have them set to `null` you should try to map out all the properties you expect your component to need.

Also, in your first code block, you have a colon after your `return:` which would evaluate to a label, meaning your data function isn't returning anything.

Comment: The colon was a mistake. I have edited my post. Let me try `Vue.set` and I will report back. Thank you.

Comment: matpie, took me a day or two to get back around to this, but I ended up taking your advice and defining all the properties upfront. Basically, I looped through the `config` prop being passed in and dynamically built up the object returned by the `data` function to get what I wanted. As a result, I had to use the syntax `$data['set' + num]` in the template to reference the properties dynamically, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, @HartleySan!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using `lodash` and a `deep watcher`..

More on `deep watcher` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    setValue() {
      this.oldPeople = _.cloneDeep(this.people);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setValue();
  },
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    changed: null,
    people: [
      { id: 0, name: "Bob", age: 27 },
      { id: 1, name: "Frank", age: 32 },
      { id: 2, name: "Joe", age: 38 }
    ],
    oldPeople: []
  },
  watch: {
    people: {
      deep: true,
      handler(after, before) {
        // Return the object that changed
        let vm = this;
        let changed = after.filter(function(p, idx) {
          return Object.keys(p).some(function(prop) {
            return p[prop] !== vm.oldPeople[idx][prop];
          });
        });
        vm.setValue();
        this.changed = changed;
      },      
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-for="(person, index) in people" v-model="people[index].age" />
    <div v-if="changed !== null">
      You changed:<br/>{{ changed }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```